# Spring Boot and JPA 2.0

Tags: hibernate, gradle, jpa-2.0, spring-boot

I want to downgrade JPA versions and use JPA 2.0. Spring Boot's Data JPA starter comes with Hibernate 4.3 which supports JPA 2.1. According to the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-dependencies-without-versions), I should be able to do this in my build.gradle:

```
'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.16.Final'
```

However [Hibernate 4.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions) is still being used. And there is no way of changing the javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa dependency to

```
'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I misinterpreted the Spring Boot guide. For anyone wanting to know the answer, it isn't as simple as Maven to just declare a version in the properties. But after looking into Gradle's docs on how replace dependencies, I came across this section:
[Substituting a dependency module with a compatible replacement](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:module_substitution)

So essentially all I need to do is this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        // Use Hibernate 4.2
        if (details.requested.name == "hibernate-entitymanager") {
            details.useTarget "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.16.Final"
        }
        // Use JPA 2.0
        if (details.requested.name == "hibernate-jpa-2.1-api") {
            details.useTarget "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final"
        }
    }
}
```

And voila!

Answer (score 0):

I using Spring boot version 1.5.8.RELEASE, and i downgraded java version of hibernate core using

```
<properties>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.21.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```